# Mono application crashes outside debugger

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I'm working on a C# 4.0 Mono app running on Ubuntu.

The application works fine when run from MonoDevelop, both in Debug and Release modes.

However if I build the application (either in Debug and Release mode) and then launch it from the command line, the app crashes with this error:

```
* Assertion: should not be reached at mini-codegen.c:1402
```

If I build the application and then run it manually by selecting Run->Debug Application from inside Mono Develop, it also runs fine.

I've tried various methods of launching the app from the command line, including:

```
./TheApp.exe
mono theApp.exe
mono --debug theApp.exe
```

I've also tried using a shell script that sets the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables first as recommended [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines%3aApplication_Deployment). All of these methods result in the same crash.

So my question is, does anyone know what MonoDevelop is doing differently when launching the app that I'm failing to do when launching it from the command line? I couldn't find anything in the project properties, but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: how exactly are you running your program? it could be that your monodevelop is using a different runtime to the one that you use from your shell (i've gotten myself into that situation before)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly is there are stacktrace after the `* Assertion: should not be reached at mini-codegen.c:1402` ?

Other issues I have seen with that error message, are normally followed by a stacktrace.

From the MonoDevelop [source code](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands/ProjectCommands.cs) clicking on the Run button in the IDE calls

**src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands/ProjectCommands.cs**.

`IdeApp.Workbench.ActiveDocument.Run (executionHandler);` from Line 284

**src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui/Document.cs**.

This calls `IdeApp.ProjectOperations.ExecuteFile (Window.ViewContent.ContentName, handler);` from Line 386

**src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/ProjectOperations.cs**.

This calls `return ExecuteFile (file, context);` on Line 1044

This calls `IAsyncOperation aop = Execute (tempProject, context);` on Line 1051

This calls `ExecuteSolutionItemAsync (monitor, entry, context);` on Line 899

This calls `entry.Execute (monitor, context, IdeApp.Workspace.ActiveConfiguration);` on Line 918

Not 100% sure after this point.

I believe this calls then calls the relevant execution command whose constructor sets

```
Command = command;
Arguments = arguments;
WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
this.environmentVariables = environmentVariables;
```

Then the StartProcess method from **src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core.Execution/ProcessService.cs** is called.

If you can identify the difference between the command, the command arguments, the working directory and the enivronment variables then you sure be able to run it with the same configuration as MonoDevelop.